# How to block a particular website?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

When i switch on my Wifi Hotspot to share my data with my son, he spends so much time in a particular website. How do I block that website in my cellphone so he will not be able to access that website?

Comment: It's not possible, blocking it on their device is possible but intercepting the connection on your device isn't possible... You could try alternative methods like blocking host connection with IP Tables on old device's... You could also ask him not to use that website when he's on your hotspot.